# Firebase multiple query bottleneck

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I have ViewPager which holds 2 different fragments. In both of the fragments, I'm trying to query firebase database with `addValueEventListener`. Here is the reference -

```
public static DatabaseReference getDatabase() {
    if (mDatabase == null) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    }
    return mDatabase;
}
```

In first `Fragment` there is something like 500+ items (takes about 8 seconds to load up), and in the second there is like 20-30. The problem is that second fragment always wait for 1st one to finish and just then queries the second one. Is there a way I can separate or do something about it? I really need the second `Fragment` to load up faster. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to query for 500+ items in one go? As a user I'd get frustrated at having to wait that long for items to load - you should think about some sort of pagination.

Comment: @MarkKeen I believe firebase do not support pagination, any ideas/sources on how to handle it?

Comment: With `Query` you can use `startAt`, `endAt`, `limitToFirst()`, `limitToLast()` etc.. shouldn't be difficult to do full list - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query - I'd try a google search, as I'm sure this problem has been solved before many times.

Comment: @MarkKeen, already looked into those, but sadly there are no working solutions that would allow pagination in listview with firebase. Spent more than 10 hours :/

Comment: Well it won't magically work? You have to implement the pagination logic?  Have you tried FirebaseUI and `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md?

Comment: Yes, also tried basic RecyclerviewAdapter. All those have their own limitations, so I went with custom Listview. Anyway, my question is regarding firebase reference itself, if there is any way to avoid that bottlenecking :/

Comment: As far as I know, Firebase calls are asynchronous.

Comment: @ReazMurshed, since 2nd fragment takes few moment to load as a short term fix I use handler, to delay first fragment for 1 sec, so users can see 2nd fragment almost instantly). Any other ideas?

Comment: I think this is a bad implementation that you have using a `Handler` to make the delay. I am trying to write an answer. However, the answer might not solve your problem directly, but I will try to propose how you might consider designing the overall Firebase call.

Comment: `addValueEventListener` adds the whole branch at once. [ChildEventListener is the recommended way to read lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events).  `onChildAdded` will be called for each child key.  This might allow Firebase to optimize the load and possibly interleave your second query

Answer (score 0):

If I had to solve this problem, I would think the overall situation a bit differently like @Mark suggested in the comments. I would have implemented a paginated query on Firebase so that I would not have to get all 500+ rows at a time.

Besides that, I would like to keep an offline storage of the data which are fetched from Firebase. So that, each time the application loads, the data is being populated in both fragments which were fetched earlier. I would run the query in the background asynchronously and the user would not have to wait for the query to finish to see the data in both fragments. Once the query is finished loading, I would have updated the views accordingly with the newly fetched data along with updating the local cache which will be needed to serve the data next time you launch the application.

If you are not interested in loading data in the background and showing the initial items from the cache and stick to your current implementation, then I would like to suggest you, manage all these things from the activity that contains the `ViewPager`. Just get the queries executed one after one, or asynchronously and get the results published to the fragments once the results are received from Firebase using `BroadcastReceiver` or something like that.

Hope that helps!